# How to disable a TextBox while retaining its style

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, styles

The default `TextBox` in WPF, once set **isEnabled** to **False**, the whole `TextBox` is grayed out. I want to protect the `TextBox.Text` from being modified and want the `TextBox` to remain its style (**ForeGround** and **Background** color).  Is there an easy work around to achieve this, other than to write the template to override the `TextBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check or set the property IsReadOnly of the TextBox to true.

Comment: @Pranay http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.isreadonly.aspx

Comment: There is indeed a TextBox.IsReadOnly property in WPF, and this is a valid answer. Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Pranay Rana： Actually there is no `IsReadOnly` property in html attributes, in wpf there is.

Comment: maybe they just don't like the way I answered, its like uncertain. I've edited it. Forgive them.

Answer (score 1):

Set `IsReadOnly` to true.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.isreadonly.aspx